# Could not autowire bean I am working with spring 3.1

Tags: spring

````
Root Cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: rinku.pms.bean.UserBean rinku.pms.controller.UserController.userBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath does not have `spring-orm` dependency. If you are using maven add this to your pom.xml or download the spring-orm and add it to your library

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```